# How to get an IMFTransform that is d3d_aware (To encode input from Windows Duplication API to H264)?

Tags: winapi, video, directx-11, ms-media-foundation, desktop-duplication

The next code should give inputInfo and outputInfo configuration to get a IMFTransform back, 
and this IMFTransform be used to encode ID3D11Texture2D(with format DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM) to H264

I understand the format DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM can be taken as a MFVideoFormat_NV12 on a IMFTranform that is D3D_AWARE . But i'm having problems to get a IMFTranform that is D3D_AWARE

```
MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO inputInfo = { MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_NV12 };
MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO outputInfo = { MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_H264 };

MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO mosiBuffer;

UINT32 unFlags = MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_LOCALMFT | MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SORTANDFILTER;

CatchError( MFTEnumEx(
    MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_ENCODER,
    unFlags,
    &inputInfo,      // Input type 
    &outputInfo,       // Output type 
    &ppActivate,
    &count
),(LPSTR)"Line 385");

CatchError(ppActivate[0]->ActivateObject(
    __uuidof(IMFTransform),
    (void**)& pTransform
),(LPSTR)"Line 392");

CatchError(pTransform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, NULL),(LPSTR)"Line 396");

IMFAttributes* imfAttributes;
CatchError(pTransform->GetAttributes(&imfAttributes), (LPSTR)"Error getAttributes from pTransform");
CatchError(imfAttributes->GetUINT32(MF_SA_D3D_AWARE,0), (LPSTR)"Error pTranform not D3D_AWARE");;
```

On the last lines, when i do :

```
CatchError(pTransform->GetAttributes(&imfAttributes), (LPSTR)"Error getAttributes from pTransform");
CatchError(imfAttributes->GetUINT32(MF_SA_D3D_AWARE,0), (LPSTR)"Error pTranform not D3D_AWARE");
```

i get the error "Error pTranform not D3D_AWARE", I don't know how to get a pTranform that is D3D_AWARE

I tried some programs on my computer with this Windows Duplication API, that then encodes it to H264 and they work

thanks in advance

Comment: Beginning in Windows 8, if using Direct3D 11 use `MF_SA_D3D11_AWARE`.

Comment: I've tried, still not available

i'm looking , maybe the solution is using FFMPEG library, i'm researching if this encoder adjusts to the hardware of the computer , or only works with NVENC(Nvidia graphics card),
and if it supports DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM as input

Answer (score 1):

You will have hard time to use Direct3D [9] aware transform with `ID3D11Texture2D` so you need Direct3D 11 awareness and, respectively, `MF_SA_D3D11_AWARE`.

Typical attributes for Intel H.264 video encoder MFT:

```
## Intel® Quick Sync Video H.264 Encoder MFT

11 Attributes:

 * MFT_TRANSFORM_CLSID_Attribute: {4BE8D3C0-0515-4A37-AD55-E4BAE19AF471} (Type VT_CLSID)
 * MF_TRANSFORM_FLAGS_Attribute: MFT_ENUM_FLAG_HARDWARE
 * MFT_ENUM_HARDWARE_VENDOR_ID_Attribute: VEN_8086 (Type VT_LPWSTR)
 * MFT_ENUM_HARDWARE_URL_Attribute: AA243E5D-2F73-48c7-97F7-F6FA17651651 (Type VT_LPWSTR)
 * MFT_INPUT_TYPES_Attributes: {3231564E-3961-42AE-BA67-FF47CCC13EED}, MFVideoFormat_NV12, MFVideoFormat_ARGB32
 * MFT_OUTPUT_TYPES_Attributes: MFVideoFormat_H264, MFVideoFormat_H264_HDCP
 * MFT_CODEC_MERIT_Attribute: 7 (Type VT_UI4)
 * MFT_SUPPORT_DYNAMIC_FORMAT_CHANGE: 1 (Type VT_UI4)
 * MF_TRANSFORM_ASYNC: 1 (Type VT_UI4)

### IMFTransform

 * Streams: Input 1, Output 1

#### Attributes

 * MF_SA_D3D11_AWARE: 1 (Type VT_UI4) <<---------------------------------
 * MFT_ENUM_HARDWARE_URL_Attribute: AA243E5D-2F73-48c7-97F7-F6FA17651651 (Type VT_LPWSTR)
 * MFT_ENUM_HARDWARE_VENDOR_ID_Attribute: VEN_8086 (Type VT_LPWSTR)
 * MFT_SUPPORT_DYNAMIC_FORMAT_CHANGE: 1 (Type VT_UI4)
 * MFT_TRANSFORM_CLSID_Attribute: {4BE8D3C0-0515-4A37-AD55-E4BAE19AF471} (Type VT_CLSID)
 * MF_VIDEO_MAX_MB_PER_SEC: 1165381 (Type VT_UI4)
 * MFT_GFX_DRIVER_VERSION_ID_Attribute: 0 (Type VT_UI8)
 * MF_TRANSFORM_ASYNC: 1 (Type VT_UI4)
```

Note that three is no Direct3D 9 awareness markup (all in all, this is already out of date).

You can use [MediaFoundationVideoEncoderTransforms tool](http://alax.info/blog/1609) to check available encoder MFTs and their properties interactively.

Next thing is that you filter transforms with `MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT` criteria. This will filter out all hardware-assisted encoders and the MFT you are getting is Microsoft's software H.264 encoder. It is neither Direct3D 9 nor Direct3D 11 aware - keep this in mind. You probably need to update your code to pick up hardware encoders.

This is the one you get:

```
## H264 Encoder MFT

6 Attributes:

 * MFT_TRANSFORM_CLSID_Attribute: {6CA50344-051A-4DED-9779-A43305165E35} (Type VT_CLSID, CLSID_CMSH264EncoderMFT)
 * MF_TRANSFORM_FLAGS_Attribute: MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT
 * MFT_INPUT_TYPES_Attributes: MFVideoFormat_IYUV, MFVideoFormat_YV12, MFVideoFormat_NV12, MFVideoFormat_YUY2
 * MFT_OUTPUT_TYPES_Attributes: MFVideoFormat_H264

### IMFTransform

 * Stream Limits: Input 1..1, Output 1..1
 * Streams: Input 1, Output 1

#### Attributes

 * MFT_ENCODER_SUPPORTS_CONFIG_EVENT: 1 (Type VT_UI4)

[...]
```

Comment: I took out the MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT filter , still isn't D3DAware
I used that program , i applied the filter Subtype : MFVideoFormat_H264, i got the same results you quoted

I'm starting to think that my computer isn't able to encode this , and/or my program with this encoding method won't be running on a generic computer , I don't know any other encoder with a track record of working with DirectX samples

thanks in advance